# how to handle null from database..?

Tags: vb.net

```
 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM enroll WHERE id = '" & idtxt.Text & "'", conn)
            Dim rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            rdr.Read()
            fnametxt.text = rdr("fname")
            lnametxt.text = rdr("lname")
            rdr.close()
```

This thing works when it returns a not null value..but some of my values have null.. And everything is messed up.. how to deal with null values? Like if the value is null it just returns a null or a blank textbox..

Comment: If Not rdr.IsDBNull(fname) Then
 fnametxt.text = rdr("fname")
End If

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Convert.IsDBNull() like that

```
If Not Convert.IsDBNull( rdr("fname") ) Then
    fnametxt.text = rdr("fname")
End If
```

It tests whether the field from a database contains database null value, which is different from .NET null value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all handle a NULL and EMPTY values from the Database like this

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT NULLIF(fname,''),NULLIF(lname,'') FROM enroll WHERE id = '" & idtxt.Text & "'", conn)
```

Now It will return Valid values or Null Values so you need to handle Null values in Code behind

use the following function in this scenario:

```
Public Shared Function NoNull(ByVal checkValue As Object, ByVal returnIfNull As Object) As Object
    If checkValue Is DBNull.Value Then
        Return returnIfNull
    Else
        Return = checkValue
    End If
End Function
```

Your code would look something like this:

```
 Dim rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
 rdr.Read()
 fnametxt.text =NoNull(rdr("fname"),"")
 lnametxt.text =NoNull(rdr("lname"),"")
 rdr.close()
```

Comment: in this line " fnametxt.text =NoNull(rdr("fname"),"") "..it says.. IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled..when i run the project..why is that ??

Comment: can you double check whether you data reader has values or not